# App freeze: Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I develop a cordova/phonegap application including several plugins. The App running on android with the cordova crosswalk plugin. After displaying the splash screen the app freezes sometimes on some special devices and produce the following error log msg:
`E/chromium(11867): [ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2263)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing`

The device list, configs and relevant logcat find above. I tried to cram the problem in different ways:

- tried different crosswalk versions, incl. latest beta
- tried different configs like hardwareAccelerated, L_DISABLE_3D, etc.
- removed several plugins

But nothing seems to effect the problem. **Any suggestions what else I could try?**

---

Following devices affected:

- HTC One (4.4.3)
- HUAWEI Ascend P7 (4.4.2)
- ASUS Zenfone 4 (4.3)

An example logcat:

```
10-07 12:42:07.362 I/ActivityManager(  757): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=***/.MainActivity} from pid 1084
10-07 12:42:07.362 D/PMS     (  757): acquireHCC(42a4e7e0): CPU_MIN_FREQ ActivityManager-MultiCore-Freq 0x100 757 1000
10-07 12:42:07.362 I/Intent  (  757): @test_code: getHtcIntentFlag: 0 obj: 1118425152
10-07 12:42:07.362 D/PMS     (  757): acquireHCC(42a146c0): CPU_MIN_FREQ PrismLaunchActivity_4 0x100 1084 10080
10-07 12:42:07.372 D/PMS     (  757): acquireWL(42858218): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  ActivityManager-Launch 0x1 757 1000
10-07 12:42:07.382 D/PMS     (  757): releaseHCC(42ad7ab0): CPU_MIN_NUM PrismScroll_2 0x400
10-07 12:42:07.382 D/PMS     (  757): releaseHCC(42ac3820): CPU_MIN_FREQ PrismScroll_2 0x100
10-07 12:42:07.392 I/FeedHostManager( 1084): [onPause]
10-07 12:42:07.392 I/FeedProviderManager( 1084): onPause
10-07 12:42:07.392 I/SocialFeedProvider( 1084): +onPause
10-07 12:42:07.392 I/SocialFeedProvider( 1084): -onPause
10-07 12:42:07.412 I/ActivityManager(  757): Start proc *** for activity ***/.MainActivity: pid=11867 uid=10195 gids={50195, 3003, 5012, 1028, 1015}
10-07 12:42:07.422 I/Launcher( 1084): updateWallpaperVisibility: true
10-07 12:42:07.492 I/TrimMemoryManager( 1084): [trimMemory] 20
10-07 12:42:07.492 W/ResourceType(  757): Skipping entry 0x7f04002b in package table 0 because it is not complex!
10-07 12:42:07.492 W/ResourceType(  757): Skipping entry 0x7f040029 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
10-07 12:42:07.542 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve static field 416 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
10-07 12:42:07.542 D/XWalkLib(11867): Pre init xwalk core in ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.552 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.552 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve method setValue to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.552 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.552 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve method setValue to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.552 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.552 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve method setValue to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.552 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.552 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve method setValue to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.552 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve object class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.562 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve object class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaResourceClient to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.562 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve method setResourceClient to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.562 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve object class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaUiClient to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.562 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve method setUIClient to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.562 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 671: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalMediaDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
10-07 12:42:07.572 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve method setXWalkViewInternalVisibility to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.572 D/XWalkLib(11867): Reserve method setSurfaceViewVisibility to ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:07.623 I/dalvikvm-heap(11867): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.256MB for 8294416-byte allocation
10-07 12:42:07.653 V/StatusBar(11867): StatusBar: initialization
10-07 12:42:07.653 D/XWalkActivity(11867): Initialize by XWalkActivity
10-07 12:42:07.653 D/XWalkLib(11867): DecompressTask started
10-07 12:42:07.653 W/ResourceType(11867): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
10-07 12:42:07.663 I/Adreno-EGL(11867): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: MINGHSUC_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.047+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.047__release_ENGG ()
10-07 12:42:07.663 I/Adreno-EGL(11867): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
10-07 12:42:07.663 I/Adreno-EGL(11867): Build Date: 03/25/14 Tue
10-07 12:42:07.663 I/Adreno-EGL(11867): Local Branch:
10-07 12:42:07.663 I/Adreno-EGL(11867): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.047
10-07 12:42:07.663 I/Adreno-EGL(11867): Local Patches: c29912293421482fd51b7f36b91ae584f9993d66 Add support for KIT_KAT
10-07 12:42:07.663 I/Adreno-EGL(11867):                  4b5d3e5bcfa9d9563f740840d7258e1c1efa6d5a egl14: add EGL_ANDROID_image_crop support
10-07 12:42:07.663 I/Adreno-EGL(11867): Recon
10-07 12:42:07.703 I/InputMethodManagerService(  757): Disable input method client, pid=1084
10-07 12:42:07.703 I/InputMethodManagerService(  757): Enable input method client, pid=11867
10-07 12:42:07.713 D/XWalkLib(11867): DecompressTask finished, 0
10-07 12:42:07.713 D/XWalkLib(11867): ActivateTask started
10-07 12:42:07.713 D/XWalkLib(11867): Attach xwalk core
10-07 12:42:07.713 D/XWalkLib(11867): [App Version] build:19.49.514.5, api:6, min_api:1
10-07 12:42:07.713 D/XWalkLib(11867): [Lib Version] build:19.49.514.5, api:6, min_api:5
10-07 12:42:07.713 D/XWalkLib(11867): XWalk core version matched
10-07 12:42:07.713 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve static field 416 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
10-07 12:42:07.713 I/System  (11867): exec(getprop ro.product.cpu.abi @ org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewDelegate.<clinit>:329)
10-07 12:42:07.743 D/XWalkLib(11867): Device ABI: armeabi-v7a
10-07 12:42:07.803 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 306
10-07 12:42:07.813 I/cr_LibraryLoader(11867): Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 8975-8976)
10-07 12:42:07.813 I/cr_LibraryLoader(11867): Expected native library version number "", actual native library version number ""
10-07 12:42:07.813 D/XWalkLib(11867): Native library is built for ARM
10-07 12:42:07.813 D/XWalkLib(11867): XWalk core architecture matched
10-07 12:42:07.813 D/XWalkLib(11867): Running in embedded mode
10-07 12:42:07.833 D/XWalkLib(11867): Dock xwalk core
10-07 12:42:07.833 D/XWalkLib(11867): Init core bridge
10-07 12:42:07.833 D/XWalkLib(11867): Init xwalk view
10-07 12:42:07.833 W/XWalkInternalResources(11867): org.xwalk.core.R$styleable.ButtonCompat is not int.
10-07 12:42:07.833 I/ActivityManager(  757): Displayed ***/.MainActivity: +431ms
10-07 12:42:07.853 W/XWalkInternalResources(11867): org.xwalk.core.R$styleable.ButtonCompat is not int.
10-07 12:42:07.863 W/XWalkInternalResources(11867): org.xwalk.core.R$styleable.ButtonCompat is not int.
10-07 12:42:07.873 W/XWalkInternalResources(11867): org.xwalk.core.R$styleable.ButtonCompat is not int.
10-07 12:42:08.063 I/cr_LibraryLoader(11867): Expected native library version number "", actual native library version number ""
10-07 12:42:08.063 I/chromium(11867): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(144)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
10-07 12:42:08.063 I/cr_BrowserStartup(11867): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
10-07 12:42:08.063 I/cr_base (11867): Extracting resource /data/data/***/app_xwalkcore/paks/xwalk.pak
10-07 12:42:08.103 I/cr_base (11867): Extracting resource /data/data/***/app_xwalkcore/icudtl.dat
10-07 12:42:08.133 I/GAV2    (11750): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
10-07 12:42:08.213 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 306
10-07 12:42:08.213 E/ApkAssets(11867): Error while loading asset assets/icudtl.dat: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/icudtl.dat
10-07 12:42:08.253 D/XWalkLib(11867): Post init xwalk core in ***.MainActivity
10-07 12:42:08.253 D/XWalkLib(11867): Init reserved class: class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences
10-07 12:42:08.253 D/XWalkLib(11867): Call reserved method: public static void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkPreferencesBridge.setValue(java.lang.String,boolean)
10-07 12:42:08.253 D/XWalkLib(11867): Init reserved class: class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences
10-07 12:42:08.253 D/XWalkLib(11867): Call reserved method: public static void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkPreferencesBridge.setValue(java.lang.String,boolean)
10-07 12:42:08.253 D/XWalkLib(11867): Init reserved class: class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences
10-07 12:42:08.253 D/XWalkLib(11867): Call reserved method: public static void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkPreferencesBridge.setValue(java.lang.String,boolean)
10-07 12:42:08.263 D/XWalkLib(11867): Init reserved class: class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences
10-07 12:42:08.263 D/XWalkLib(11867): Call reserved method: public static void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkPreferencesBridge.setValue(java.lang.String,boolean)
10-07 12:42:08.263 D/XWalkLib(11867): Init reserved object: class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView
10-07 12:42:08.263 W/cr_media(11867): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
10-07 12:42:08.273 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
10-07 12:42:08.273 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 12458: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
10-07 12:42:08.273 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 12462: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
10-07 12:42:08.273 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 310: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
10-07 12:42:08.273 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 318: Landroid/app/Activity;.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
10-07 12:42:08.273 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 807: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.isPermissionRevokedByPolicy (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
10-07 12:42:08.283 E/chromium(11867): [ERROR:xwalk_platform_notification_service.cc(142)] Not implemented reached in virtual bool xwalk::XWalkPlatformNotificationService::GetDisplayedPersistentNotifications(content::BrowserContext*, std::__1::set<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >*)
10-07 12:42:08.283 E/chromium(11867): [ERROR:xwalk_browser_context.cc(80)] Failed to read preference, error num: 0
10-07 12:42:08.333 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/ViewStructure;)
10-07 12:42:08.333 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/ViewStructure;)
10-07 12:42:08.333 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/ViewStructure;)
10-07 12:42:08.333 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12425: Landroid/view/ViewStructure;.setClassName (Ljava/lang/String;)V
10-07 12:42:08.343 W/dalvikvm(11867): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/chromium/content/browser/FloatingWebActionModeCallback; (1751)
10-07 12:42:08.343 W/dalvikvm(11867): Link of class 'Lorg/chromium/content/browser/FloatingWebActionModeCallback;' failed
10-07 12:42:08.343 E/dalvikvm(11867): Could not find class 'org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback', referenced from method org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.startFloatingActionMode
10-07 12:42:08.343 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2751 (Lorg/chromium/content/browser/FloatingWebActionModeCallback;) in Lorg/chromium/content/browser/ContentViewCore;
10-07 12:42:08.353 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/ViewStructure;)
10-07 12:42:08.353 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12424: Landroid/view/ViewStructure;.setChildCount (I)V
10-07 12:42:08.353 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12424: Landroid/view/ViewStructure;.setChildCount (I)V
10-07 12:42:08.353 W/dalvikvm(11867): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/chromium/content/browser/FloatingWebActionModeCallback; (1751)
10-07 12:42:08.353 W/dalvikvm(11867): Link of class 'Lorg/chromium/content/browser/FloatingWebActionModeCallback;' failed
10-07 12:42:08.363 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/inputmethod/CursorAnchorInfo;)
10-07 12:42:08.363 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12805: Landroid/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager;.updateCursorAnchorInfo (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/inputmethod/CursorAnchorInfo;)V
10-07 12:42:08.363 D/cr_Ime  (11867): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:27] Constructor
10-07 12:42:08.383 D/PMS     (  757): releaseHCC(42a7bc28): CPU_MIN_NUM PrismLaunchActivity_4 0x400
10-07 12:42:08.383 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 1414: Landroid/media/MediaCodecList;.<init> (I)V
10-07 12:42:08.383 D/PMS     (  757): releaseHCC(42a146c0): CPU_MIN_FREQ PrismLaunchActivity_4 0x100
10-07 12:42:08.413 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12744: Landroid/view/accessibility/CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle;.hasBackgroundColor ()Z
10-07 12:42:08.423 D/XWalkLib(11867): Init reserved object: class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaResourceClient
10-07 12:42:08.433 D/XWalkLib(11867): Call reserved method: public void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.setResourceClientSuper(org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkResourceClientBridge)
10-07 12:42:08.433 D/XWalkLib(11867): Init reserved object: class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaUiClient
10-07 12:42:08.433 D/XWalkLib(11867): Call reserved method: public void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.setUIClientSuper(org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkUIClientBridge)
10-07 12:42:08.433 D/XWalkLib(11867): Call reserved method: public void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.setXWalkViewInternalVisibilitySuper(int)
10-07 12:42:08.433 D/XWalkLib(11867): Call reserved method: public void org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.setSurfaceViewVisibilitySuper(int)
10-07 12:42:08.433 D/XWalkLib(11867): ActivateTask finished, 1
10-07 12:42:08.443 I/XWalkWebViewEngine(11867): Iterate assets/xwalk-extensions folder
10-07 12:42:08.624 W/chromium(11867): [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/***-1/libxwalkdummy.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
10-07 12:42:08.624 W/chromium(11867): [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/***-1/libxwalkdummy.so
10-07 12:42:08.624 W/chromium(11867): [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/***-1/libxwalkcore.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
10-07 12:42:08.624 W/chromium(11867): [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/***-1/libxwalkcore.so
10-07 12:42:08.634 I/Choreographer(11867): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/chromium/net/NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect$MyNetworkCallback; (352)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): Link of class 'Lorg/chromium/net/NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect$MyNetworkCallback;' failed
10-07 12:42:08.644 E/dalvikvm(11867): Could not find class 'org.chromium.net.NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect$MyNetworkCallback', referenced from method org.chromium.net.NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect.<init>
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3514 (Lorg/chromium/net/NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect$MyNetworkCallback;) in Lorg/chromium/net/NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect;
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1704: Landroid/net/Network;.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.644 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/NetworkRequest;)
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/chromium/net/NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect$MyNetworkCallback; (352)
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): Link of class 'Lorg/chromium/net/NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect$MyNetworkCallback;' failed
10-07 12:42:08.654 I/chromium(11867): [INFO:xwalk_extension_renderer_controller.cc(43)] EXTENSION PROCESS DISABLED.
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1697: Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;.getAllNetworks ()[Landroid/net/Network;
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1700: Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;.getNetworkInfo (Landroid/net/Network;)Landroid/net/NetworkInfo;
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1700: Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;.getNetworkInfo (Landroid/net/Network;)Landroid/net/NetworkInfo;
10-07 12:42:08.654 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/Network;)
10-07 12:42:08.664 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1698: Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;.getNetworkCapabilities (Landroid/net/Network;)Landroid/net/NetworkCapabilities;
10-07 12:42:08.664 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/net/NetworkRequest;)
10-07 12:42:08.664 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1702: Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;.registerNetworkCallback (Landroid/net/NetworkRequest;Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager$NetworkCallback;)V
10-07 12:42:08.664 W/dalvikvm(11867): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1703: Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;.unregisterNetworkCallback (Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager$NetworkCallback;)V
10-07 12:42:08.664 D/PMS     (  757): releaseWL(42858218): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  ActivityManager-Launch 0x1
10-07 12:42:08.694 E/libEGL  (11867): validate_display:259 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
10-07 12:42:08.714 W/cr_BindingManager(11867): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 11867
10-07 12:42:08.864 W/CpuWake (  757): >>nativeReleaseCpuPerfWakeLock()
10-07 12:42:08.864 W/CpuWake (  757): <<nativeReleaseCpuPerfWakeLock()
10-07 12:42:08.864 W/CpuWake (  757): >>release mCpuPerf_cpu_count wakelock
10-07 12:42:08.864 W/CpuWake (  757): <<release mCpuPerf_cpu_count wakelock
10-07 12:42:08.864 W/CpuWake (  757): >>release mCpuPerf_Freq wakelock
10-07 12:42:08.864 W/CpuWake (  757): <<release mCpuPerf_Freq wakelock
10-07 12:42:08.864 D/PMS     (  757): releaseHCC(42a9afd0): CPU_MIN_NUM ActivityManager-MultiCore-Num 0x400
10-07 12:42:08.864 D/PMS     (  757): releaseHCC(42a4e7e0): CPU_MIN_FREQ ActivityManager-MultiCore-Freq 0x100
10-07 12:42:08.984 D/JsMessageQueue(11867): Set native->JS mode to OnlineEventsBridgeMode
10-07 12:42:09.424 V/StatusBar(11867): Executing action: _ready
10-07 12:42:09.424 W/CordovaPlugin(11867): Attempted to send a second callback for ID: StatusBar32585383
10-07 12:42:09.424 W/CordovaPlugin(11867): Result was: "Invalid action"
10-07 12:42:09.535 E/chromium(11867): [ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2263)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
10-07 12:42:10.315 I/chromium(11867): [INFO:SkFontMgr_android_parser.cpp(595)] [SkFontMgr Android Parser] '/system/etc/fonts.xml' could not be opened
10-07 12:42:10.315 I/chromium(11867):
10-07 12:42:10.315 I/chromium(11867): [INFO:SkFontMgr_android_parser.cpp(595)] [SkFontMgr Android Parser] '/vendor/etc/fallback_fonts.xml' could not be opened
10-07 12:42:10.315 I/chromium(11867):
10-07 12:42:10.676 D/PhoneStatusBar(  911): Status bar WINDOW_STATE_HIDING
10-07 12:42:10.766 I/chromium(11867): [INFO:CONSOLE(900)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'CitiesCollection' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/app/ressources/bower_components/requirejs/require.js (900)
10-07 12:42:11.076 D/PhoneStatusBar(  911): Status bar WINDOW_STATE_HIDDEN
10-07 12:42:12.688 D/PMS     (  757): acquireWL(42479e30): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  NlpWakeLock 0x1 24221 10020
10-07 12:42:12.698 D/PMS     (  757): acquireWL(421aa8b0): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  NlpWakeLock 0x1 24221 10020
10-07 12:42:12.698 D/WifiService(  757): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@42aa4de0}
10-07 12:42:12.708 D/PMS     (  757): acquireWL(42a29c70): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  AlarmManager 0x1 757 1000
10-07 12:42:12.718 V/AlarmManager(  757): sending alarm PendingIntent{42ba00f8: PendingIntentRecord{4286af78 com.google.android.gms broadcastIntent}}, i=com.google.android.gms.nlp.ALARM_WAKEUP_LOCATOR, t=2, cnt=1, w=2417663301, Int=0
10-07 12:42:12.718 D/PMS     (  757): releaseWL(42a29c70): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  AlarmManager 0x1
10-07 12:42:12.718 D/PMS     (  757): releaseWL(42479e30): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  NlpWakeLock 0x1
10-07 12:42:12.858 D/WifiService(  757): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@42aa4de0}
10-07 12:42:12.868 D/PMS     (  757): releaseWL(421aa8b0): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  NlpWakeLock 0x1
10-07 12:42:17.403 D/PMS     (  757): acquireWL(435b97f0): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  AlarmManager 0x1 757 1000
10-07 12:42:17.403 V/AlarmManager(  757): sending alarm PendingIntent{42a337e0: PendingIntentRecord{4273f320 com.android.vending startService}}, i=null, t=0, cnt=1, w=1475836937154, Int=0
10-07 12:42:17.403 D/PMS     (  757): releaseWL(435b97f0): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  AlarmManager 0x1
10-07 12:42:17.673 D/Finsky  ( 2449): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
```

Cordova plugins:

```
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file@3.0.0",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media@1.0.1",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen@2.1.0",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar@1.0.1",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration@1.2.0",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation@1.0.1",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.3.0",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device@1.0.1",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@0.6.0",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-preferences@0.7.7",
    "cordova plugin add https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer.git",
    "cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information",
    "cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git",
    "cordova plugin add cc.fovea.cordova.purchase@5.x --variable BILLING_KEY='<%= BILLING_KEY %>'",
    "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@1.8.x",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help others. In my case some initialization **before the first view is rendered** caused this error. Both single of the following points seems to bring on the problem unreproducible from time to time:

- unzipping some kB and copy some files to the app data directory
- parsing JSON into a backbone Collection via ajax